# Vectorized implementation of a table lookup loop SOLVED

Tags: python, pandas, lookup

I have two pandas dataframes, df_map has the data I am working with and df_4pc is a lookup table. I want to include the latitute and longitude in my df_map by using postcodes.

That is how they look:

```
>> df_4pc.head()
idx  postcode   woonplaats  latitude    longitude
0   1000    Amsterdam   52.336243   4.869444
1   1001    Amsterdam   52.364240   4.883358
2   1002    Amsterdam   52.364240   4.883358
3   1003    Amsterdam   52.364240   4.883358
4   1005    Amsterdam   52.364240   4.883358
```

```
>> df_map.head()
    location_postcode   latitude    longitude
visit_id            
12765996        1000    0.0          0.0
12764909        1005    0.0          0.0
11698683        1002    0.0          0.0
11665112        1003    0.0          0.0
12638508        1005    0.0          0.0
```

For the task, I tried using df.lookup, but I get a keyrror:

```
>> df_4pc.lookup(df_map["location_postcode"], ["postcode"]*len(df_map))

KeyError: 'One or more row labels was not found'
```

However, I made sure that only postcodes present in df_4pc are used in df_map (the other values were discarded). I have an implementation running, but the dataset is quite large and it takes a few hours to run the whole thing with my loop implementation:

```
for i in tqdm_notebook(df_map.index.tolist()):
    df_map.at[i, "latitude"] = df_4pc[df_4pc["postcode"] == df_map.at[i, "location_postcode"]]["latitude"]
    df_map.at[i, "longitude"] = df_4pc[df_4pc["postcode"] == df_map.at[i, "location_postcode"]]["longitude"]
```

That is my expected output:

```
>> df_map.head()
    location_postcode   latitude    longitude
visit_id            
12765996        1000    52.336243   4.869444
12764909        1005    52.364240   4.883358
11698683        1002    52.364240   4.883358
11665112        1003    52.364240   4.883358
12638508        1005    52.364240   4.883358
```

I am very unsure of why I have this key error. I looked on multiple threads of stack overflow, especially the ones related to df.lookup, but I could not find anything that worked for me.

The final question is: How can I get an efficient implementation for this lookup table?

**Solution**
pandas join does the job in a second for a database of +1M lines.

```
coords = df_4pc.set_index('postcode')
df_map = df_map.loc[:, ['location_postcode'].copy()].join(coords, on='location_postcode')
```

Comment: based on the above 2 dfs, what is the expected output?

Comment: I indeed forgot to add the expected output. Thanks for the tip. Basically, I want to modify the df_map to include the latitude and longitude.

Comment: i dont think it still matches as `df_4pc.head()` postcode doesnt match `df_map` postcode in the example. I would suggest you to create a sample which abides by the explaination you have given. Let me know If I am wrong. :)

Comment: I don't understand your point. What does not match? And I should create a sample of what?

Comment: postcodes of both the dfs doesnt match for the example. so lookup wont have any results.

Comment: only the first five lines of the df are shown there. df_4pc has 4699 postcodes and df_map has about a million lines. All the postcodes in df_map are present in df_4pc (there is an working script making sure this is true).

Comment: so you want us to assume and replicate? not happening. you have to create a sample df which matches your statements.

Comment: The downvote wasn't necessary. Took me a while longer to understand what you meant by "create a sample". I changed the examples so it is replicable.

Comment: retracted the downvote. i think you need `m=df_map[['location_postcode']].merge(df_4pc,left_on='location_postcode',right_on='postcode')` and then call `m[df_map.columns]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided your data as an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I can't verify but [DataFrame.join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join) should work.

```py
coords = df_4pc.set_index('postcode')
df_map = (df_map.loc[:, ['location_postcode'].copy()
          .join(coords, on='location_postcode'))
```

Comment: Does in a second what the loop was doing in an hour!